# WordPress how to encode the searched URL

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, urlencode

I want to make a search URL look like this:

> `example.com/search/search+query?post_type=product`.

I have tried many methods including this:

```php
wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/?s=" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) . "&post_type=" . urlencode( get_query_var( 'post_type' ) ) );
```

and this:

```php
wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ). "?post_type=". urlencode( get_query_var( 'post_type' ) ) ) );
```

but the result I am getting:

> `example.com/search/search+query%3Fpost_type%3Dproduct`

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet will do the trick for you!

```
$decoded_url = urldecode('example.com/search/search+query%3Fpost_type%3Dproduct');

echo $decoded_url;
```

And the result would be:

```
example.com/search/search query?post_type=product
```

Answer (score 0):

**urlencode_deep( mixed $value )**

Navigates through an array, object, or scalar, and encodes the values to be used in a URL.

**$value** - (mixed) (Required) The array or string to be encoded.

```
function urlencode_deep( $value ) {
    return map_deep( $value, 'urlencode' );
}
```